# Logical AND ,OR CAML Query not working in External List

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, client-object-model, caml-query, external-content-type, external-list

I am using ClientContext Class and CAML query to retrieve items from External List in sharepoint 2010.I have built the query with Logical AND Condition in CAML Query like this

```
 string sDataFilter =<Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name="Year" /><Value Type="Text">1960</Value></Eq><Contains><FieldRef Name="ChartName" /><Value Type="Text">Chart1</Value></Contains></And></Where></Query>
```

When I exceute the following code

```
List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetById(new Guid(list));
               CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
               string queryContext = "<View><Query>" + sDataFilter + "</Query>" + viewFieldsContext + "</View>";
               camlQuery.ViewXml = queryContext;
               ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
               clientContext.Load(collListItem);
               clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I am getting the empty ListItemCollection.I have cross verified with the **U2U CAML Query Builder** the data is empty only. So in External List the caml query is working fine for sorting and simple filter query like Where,EqualTo condition I can't use Logical conditions in the query ? If yes how could I achieve this using caml query
Could anyone help me to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Is it correct that you're "sDataFilter" starts and ends with the <Query>-tag and you place it within another <Query>-tag in your "queryContext"?

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove
`<Query> </Query>`
tag inside sDataFilter.

Regards